# Angles Between the Intersections of Three Planes

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

There are three planes, **A**, **B**, and **C**, all of which intersect at a single point, **P**. The angles between the planes are given: $$\angle\mathbf{AB}=\alpha$$ $$\angle\mathbf{BC}=\beta$$ $$\angle\mathbf{CA}=\gamma$$ $$0\lt\alpha,\beta,\gamma\le\frac{\pi}{2}$$

The intersection of any two of these planes form lines. The intersection of **AB** is $\mathbf{\overline{AB}}$, the intersection of **BC** is $\mathbf{\overline{BC}}$, and the intersection of **CA** is $\mathbf{\overline{CA}}$. It is given that none of these lines are parallel to each other and that they all intersect at the same single point, **P**.

Please express the lesser of the two angles formed by the intersection of these lines in terms of $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$:
$$\angle\mathbf{\overline{AB}\;\overline{BC}}=?$$ $$\angle\mathbf{\overline{AB}\;\overline{CA}}=?$$ $$\angle\mathbf{\overline{BC}\;\overline{CA}}=?$$

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to help you without knowing what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(QPR)$, $(SPR)$ and $(QPS)$ be our planes, where $\measuredangle QPR=\alpha$, $\measuredangle SPR=\beta$, $\measuredangle QPS=\gamma$.

Let $\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}\subset\left(0^{\circ},90^{\circ}\right)$.

We can assume that $\measuredangle QRP=\measuredangle SRP=90^{\circ}$. Also, let $PR=a$.

Thus, $$QR=a\tan\alpha,$$
$$SR=a\tan\beta,$$ 
$$PQ=\frac{a}{\cos\alpha},$$
$$PS=\frac{a}{\cos\beta}$$ and
$$QS^2=\left(\frac{a}{\cos\alpha}\right)^2+\left(\frac{a}{\cos\beta}\right)^2-2\cdot\frac{a}{\cos\alpha}\cdot\frac{a}{\cos\beta}\cdot\cos\gamma.$$
Let $\measuredangle QRS=\phi$.

Thus,
$$\left(\frac{a}{\cos\alpha}\right)^2+\left(\frac{a}{\cos\beta}\right)^2-2\cdot\frac{a}{\cos\alpha}\cdot\frac{a}{\cos\beta}\cdot\cos\gamma=$$
$$=\left(\frac{a\sin^2\alpha}{\cos\alpha}\right)^2+\left(\frac{a\sin^2\beta}{\cos\beta}\right)^2-2\cdot\frac{a\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}\cdot\frac{a\sin\beta}{\cos\beta}\cdot\cos\phi$$ or
$$\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta-2\cos\alpha\cos\beta\cos\gamma=$$
$$=\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\beta+\sin^2\beta\cos^2\alpha-2\sin\alpha\sin\beta\cos\alpha\cos\beta\cos\phi$$ or
$$2\cos^2\alpha\cos^2\beta-2\cos\alpha\cos\beta\cos\gamma=-2\sin\alpha\sin\beta\cos\alpha\cos\beta\cos\phi$$ or
$$\cos\phi=\frac{\cos\gamma-\cos\alpha\cos\beta}{\sin\alpha\sin\beta}.$$

I changed your notations, but I am sure that you can get relevant formula with your notation.

By the same way you can get needed identities.

See also here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry

Comment: Do I need to know a new angle $\phi$, or is this one of the angles I am trying to solve for?

Comment: @TheNewGuy In our case $\phi$ it's $\gamma$ in your notations. I just showed how you can get  laws from the link.